# How to create different view for different exception laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to set different view blade template for different exception and also pass the errors on the following page.  I tried out the following code but it's not working. It always goes to the else portion of the code and run the `parent::render($request, $e);`code.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($e))
    {
        if($e instanceof InvalidArgumentException)
        {
            return response()->view('front.missing', [], 404);
        }elseif($e instanceof ErrorException){
            return response()->view('front.missing2', [], 404);
        }
        return $this->renderHttpException($e);
    }else{
        if($e instanceof InvalidArgumentException)
        {
            return response()->view('errors.204', []);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }

}
```

Where is the problem here and what I will do now?

Comment: what triggers `InvalidArgumentException` exception ?

Comment: try to get non-property object.

Answer (score 0):

InvalidArgumentException is not a child class of HttpException, so it always goes to the else portion.

Comment: I want to set different view blade template for different exception or error then what I will do?

Comment: For exceptions of type HttpException, you just need to add view blade templates for different status codes under resources/views/errors. e.g. 404.blade.php, 500.blade.php, laravel will match the status code and template for you. For other exceptions you can customize the response as what you've already done in your code.

Comment: 404, 500 are working well as you said. How I get the status code? 
Earlier I already said that my code is not working as my expectation.